# Where do driver developers get hardware specifications?

Tags: operating-system, drivers

This may be a silly question, but where exactly do OS/driver developers get hardware documentation of devices they want to write drivers for? Detailed hardware specification is rarely made freely available by manufacturers, so how do open-source OS developers get all the necessary documentation? I know my question is very general - would it be easier to answer if I asked specifically about Linux?

Comment: Not *that* rarely. Last time I wrote a driver on my own, rather than for an employer, I got in touch with the company making the hardware and asked them for the white paper. The US branch turned down my request -- I tried someone at their Taiwan office, and they handed over the docs.

Comment: These days, though, drivers are often as not written by the device manufacturer themselves. Linux is an actual *market* these days. And then you've got standardized interfaces that everyone implements to -- at which point you can just get the docs straight from the standards body, and if the manufacturer doesn't comply to the letter, that's a bug in their hardware.

Comment: (And then there are... let's say... *other* approaches. If you've got a bus analyzer, or a virtualization setup with PCI passthrough (or whatever kind of passthrough is appropriate to the device you're trying to figure out), there's a lot you can do there too).

Comment: ...on the "for an employer" part -- there are a fair number of shops that do kernel work. Back at MontaVista, many of our most important partners/clients were hardware vendors who wanted to sell into embedded space, and paid us to make sure that there existed an embedded distribution and set of tools that supported that hardware well. This did of course include doing kernel work, and submitting that work upstream -- with the folks making the hardware providing not just a whitepaper but sample hardware and often engineering support.

Comment: I'm glad someone answered my question :) I'll try to be more specific. Suppose I have a typical mouse and I want to write a basic driver for it and test if it actually works. I don't know its manufacturer or no hardware specs are made available. Where am I supposed to start? My development OS would be Linux.

Comment: If you have a typical mouse, then it'll support the USB HID standards. Those are actual, published standards; you don't need anything from the hardware manufacturer. (Actually, since Linux already ships with HID drivers, it'll already work).

Comment: ...but let's say you had a mouse built for CAD/drafting work in the 1980s that doesn't support USB. In *that* case, I'd do one of the other things I suggested above -- actually *using* that hardware from a VM (using serial-, USB- or PCI-passthrough in that order of preference) running a guest OS where it's already supported, and watching the traffic from outside of it.

Comment: Or if I had a *budget*, I might go the Chinese-wall approach of hiring someone to write a specification based on reverse-engineering the original driver, and then having a completely different someone write an implementation to that specification without having ever seen the device (this is how the IBM PC BIOS was legally cloned by Compaq -- ensuring that your engineers building the implementation have never seen the copyrighted original, but only a specification describing what interfaces that copyrighted original operates).

Comment: How about PS/2 mouse? Would it be a lot harder to write a driver for it than for USB mouse?

Comment: Again, there's a single standard that all PS/2 mice comply with, so any new PS/2 mouse wouldn't require a new driver -- it would work with the existing driver.

Comment: ...well, with a caveat that there might be extra features that aren't supported without a driver specific to the device; such is the case with the Microsoft Intellimouse. See http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2mouse/ for a detailed description of the protocol, including Microsoft's extensions -- which should give you a decent idea of how implementing any other vendor's extensions would work.

Comment: Would the above principle (that there exist some general, freely available standards hardware manufacturers must, or at least, should conform to) also apply to, say, keyboard or more complicated pieces of hardware, such as sound card, graphics card or network card? Could I, theoretically, write my own device driver for any hardware modern PC is equipped with? Where should I look for appropriate documents?

Comment: Keyboard, definitely. Graphics card, yes but only for basic functionality (everyone supports the VESA baseline, but fancy acceleration bits are proprietary). And in recent hardware there are EFI runtime services as a way to have a standard way to interoperate with hardware drivers which can actually be shipped on the hardware itself until a better-optimized driver has been loaded by the OS. There are standardized interfaces for USB-connected network, video and sound, but not as much so for PCI hardware.